Keycloak (ver #26.0.0) custom provider packaging and deployment
I am relatively new to keycloak and have started using as our new identity and access management tool. I have been developing a custom authenticator provider, which makes use of certain maven packages like ms-graph, azure-identity etc. along with keycloak dependencies in pom.xml.
While, the code compiles well and packages using default maven build and package tools / commands in IntellJ IDE. However, when deployed / copied jar file to keycloak provider directory and restart docker container (keycloak), it blows and doesn't build and fails to run container. The error I see in docker logs are something ... The DelayedHandler was closed before any children handlers were configured.
Could you point to right documentation or guide to build and package custom providers with external dependencies like ms-graph, azure-identity packages ? What is that I'm missing to include or setup ?
